# python3 check ldap username and password in a safe way

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, python-ldap

How can I check in python3 whether the username and password are valid?

I already ask the user for username and password:

```
import getpass
import sys

sys.stdout.write("- Enter your (LDAP) username : ")
    username = input().lower()
password=getpass.getpass("- Enter your (LDAP) password : ")
```

I know I could use `ldapwhoami` to check the validity, something like:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['ldapwhoami', '-h', 'ldap-server', '-D', '{}@domain'.format(username)', '-x', 
                '-w', password], check=True)
```

but then a process would be spawned in which the password would be visible. So how could I check these credentials in a safe way? Either hiding the password, either using a python library or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this using the `python-ldap` library, thus no separate process is spawned.

```
import ldap
try:
    # build a client
    ldap_client = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap-server.domain")
    # perform a synchronous bind
    ldap_client.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    ldap_client.simple_bind_s("{}@domain".format(username), password)
    print("LDAP credentials were good!")
except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
    ldap_client.unbind()
    print("LDAP credentials incorrect!")
```

Comment: Try that with password set to "". You might be a bit unpleasantly surprised :-/

https://medium.com/@alpolishchuk/how-i-encountered-a-python-ldap-feature-ea3c6c4f9f11